# Using String Functions (LEFT, RIGHT, MID) in Select By Attributes against a File Geodatabase using ArcMap 10

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, sql, file-geodatabase, select-by-attribute

I finally (albeit reluctantly) made the switch from a personal geodatabase (pGDB) to a file geodatabse (fGDB) not too long ago.  The main reason it took so long to switch has to do with how Select by Attributes deals with string functions.

For example, I used to be able to easily select all records where the first character of a particular field starts with "A".

```
left([Some_Field],1 = "A")
```

This works without a hitch when querying against a pGDB.  However, try to do the same thing against a fGDB.

```
left("Some_Field",1 = "A")
```

This returns the following error:

```
There was a problem selecting
An invalid SQL statement was used.
```

I realize I can use the field calculator to calculate a new field equal to the first character of some other field.  But who wants to do that every time?

Is there a way to use string functions inside Select By Attributes?

Comment: Rayner, I still use pgdb for storing output I want to analyse in another application such as minitab as you can use odbc to suck data out of the pdgb, you still can't  do that with a fgdb. Don't  give up on them yet! :)

Comment: I really wish Esri would (could?) standardize SQL syntax for all of the different data formats.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your queries should follow the SQL format discussed [here](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=About_building_an_SQL_expression).  For what you're looking for, you can use something like this:

```
"Some_Field" LIKE 'A%'
```

The % is a wild card, so this would return records that have values in "Some_Field" that start with 'A'.

Comment: This works.  For some reason in the back of my mind I stayed away from LIKE . . . maybe this comes from the old 8.x days when it was a bit more unreliable than it is now.

Comment: Likewise, '%A' selects records that end in 'A'  You can use '%A%' but that selects all records that have an 'A' anywhere in the field.  The only thing that really remains unsolved is the MID function.  I used to query mid([FacilityID],2,4) <> [TaxMapCalc] against a pGDB but it doesn't work against a fGDB.

Comment: It might not be as easy, but you can also use the [sql wildcard "underscore"](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp) which represents only a single character. So your mid query could be something like: "Some_Field" LIKE '_ _A%' (but with no spaces)

Answer (score 8):

You can use Substring("fieldname", start, length) to mimick, left(), right() and mid() functions when querying a fgdb.

Left and Mid are obvious.

To extract the right 2 characters would be Substring("fieldname", char_length("fieldname") - 1), 2).

Column numbers are 1-based.

Comment: I see where it shows Substring here: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000033000000 but I'm at a loss as how to use this inside the ArcMap Select By Attributes window.

Comment: `SUBSTRING("Field" FROM 1 FOR 2) in ('AA', 'AR')`
Will return all records where the field attributes start with 'AA' OR 'AR'.
Same as `"Field" LIKE 'AA%' OR "Field" LIKE 'AR%'` But nice when you don't want to write a bunch of OR's for a long list.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
left("Some_Field",1) = 'A'
```

where the comparison operator is outside the parentheses, and the string value is in single quotes.

Note that string searches are case sensitive in a file geodb. So you might also have to use the UPPER or LOWER functions, or search for 'A' or 'a'.

Comment: The query doesn't work in ArcMap 10.1 against a file geodatabase.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone landing here searching for a reason why the left() function doesn't work in arcgis, this is what I found:

`LEFT()` and `RIGHT()` don't work for fgdb's.  You must use `SUBSTRING(field FROM start for NumChars)`

The correct syntax for the SUBSTRING function is:

`SUBSTRING("Field" FROM 1 FOR 3)`
 - this example returns everything from the first char to the third char (if the field value was Apple, this would return App).