# Using function to query text field in ArcGIS Select By Attributes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, query, select-by-attribute

I can do this:

[image]

And get result:

[image]

On the other hand, when I do this:

[image]

I get an error message:

[image]

Why query using function is working on numeric field and is not working on text in both shapefile and file geodatabase?

Comment: it doesn't appear to like the `"` marks around your field name.  Works fine on a gdb layer, but not a shapefile with the quote marks, possibly because `LEFT` also works on text e.g. `"Region"`

Comment: try using `"Region" LIKE 'Auc%'` instead

Comment: Query parsing is different for every different data source, so stating the data source is critical

Comment: What kind of data source is this?  For a File Geodatabases you could use - SUBSTRING(REGION FROM 1 FOR 3)

Comment: @Midavalo yes I know about LIKE. The reason I am asking is because I'd like to compare two fields. Functions ARE working on numeric fields and they are not working for string fields

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35136/using-string-functions-left-right-mid-in-select-by-attributes-against-a-file

Comment: @RichardFairhurst post it as answer, I'll accept it. Just tested SUBSTRING(REGION FROM 1 FOR 3)=SUBSTRING(REG FROM 1 FOR 3) and it works. Any chance to do similar thing on dBase table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a File Geodatabases you could use -

SUBSTRING(REGION FROM 1 FOR 3) = SUBSTRING(REG FROM 1 FOR 3)

For a Shapefile use:

SUBSTRING(REGION, 1, 3) = SUBSTRING(REG, 1, 3)

I got the shapefile syntax from this Technical Article - [HowTo:  Compare a field with a substring in another field](http://support.esri.com/EN/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/28388)