# Equivalent of 'Left' function in Select_analysis

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, select-by-attribute

I tried to find the equivalent of Left fuction because it doesn't work in ArcGis. I found a post that suggested the word substring:

the query is:

```
WHERE (IAS.C_A)<>Left([C_A1],5)));
```

and I tried:

```
"('IAS.C_A')<>substring(['C_A1' from 1 for 5])"
```

in the function:

```
arcpy.Select_analysis(in_features=TW,out_feature_class='ac',
where_clause= "('IAS.C_A')<>substring(['C_A1' from 1 for 5]))";
```

but shows error in syntax.

**ANSWER**

```
"'IAS.C_A'<>'substring(C_A1, 1 ,5'")
```

For each part we add a single quote and a double one in the start and one in the end of the where clause.

Comment: Can you included the syntax error you received in your post?

Comment: Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 1)

Comment: You are missing the end parenthesis. Also remove the ;. What exactly do you want to select?

Comment: I want to select where (IAS.C_A)<>Left([C_A1],5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know [this answer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/cityengine/2016/cga/cga-substring-function.htm) was meant for city engine but the function should work the same.

`substring` takes 3 arguments, `string`, `start`, and the last one is either `stop position` or `length`.

the second answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35136/using-string-functions-left-right-mid-in-select-by-attributes-against-a-file) has an example of how to use it.

it is worth taking another look at the [documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/select.htm), since the sql query examples it [redirects to](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/sql-reference-for-query-expressions-used-in-arcgis.htm) do use the `LEFT` function.

**EDIT**
while `LEFT` did not work for me, testing with the natural earth countries layer i did use substring succefully, here is the example taking only the first letter from **TYPE**:

```
arcpy.Select_analysis(in_features="test", out_feature_class="C:/Projects/Natural_Earth/New File Geodatabase.gdb/test1", where_clause="substring(TYPE,1,2) = 'S'")
```

Comment: So is it accepting LEFT? how is the correct version of the query in question. Thanks

Comment: have you tried running it like the example in the sql reference?   `LEFT(C_A1,5) `

Comment: Yes, it shows error all the time. I have tried so many combinations.

Comment: added a working example to my answer. @user51332

Comment: I found it finally. Thanks for the ideas. See the question to see the answer.